# Rendering problems при создании пустого приложения

Tags: android, android-studio

При создании пустого приложения в Android Studio возникают проблемы:

> rendering problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Подскажите в чем может быть дело?
P.S. Android Studio переустанавливал - не помогает[image: Принт скрин проблемы]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь для превью окна это нормально, в нем очень часто какие то проблемы обозначаются которых на самом деле нет. Точнее они есть только в этом самом превью, при заливке на девайс или эмулятор всё будет работать нормально. Это окно довольно плохо переваривает новые и кастомные контролы не смотря на то что они уже во всю используются в стандартных шаблонах.

Остаётся лишь молиться что бы когданить в коде всех новых контролов расставят где нужно проверку на `View.isInEditMode()`. А пока просто игнорируем эти сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать понизить API в layout[image: введите сюда описание изображения]